# Collapse index sub-items on to the parent line

Tags: indexing, imakeidx

I have a long document with lots of index entries defined like `\index{Surname!Name}`, and I've decided that for one particular purpose, I would like the index formatted as if I had written `\index{Surname, Name}` throughout, but I don't particularly want to edit each use of the `\index`.  Is there a strategy for doing this?  In case it's relevant, I'm using `imakeidx` and XeLaTeX.

I don't think a MWE really adds anything, but it seems to be expected all the same:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage[columns=1]{idxlayout}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
John\index{Smith!John} and William Smith\index{Smith!William} 
were brothers.  Jack Jones\index{Jones!Jack} is another person.
\printindex
\end{document}
```

What I want is for the index to read

> Jones, Jack, 1 
>   Smith, John, 1 
>   Smith, William, 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: See the shorter version at the end of the answer.

Perhaps it is possible to play with catcodes or to change the `\indexentry` command, another way is to use `l3regex` and replace the `!` with `,`, by a small redefinition of the `\index` command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{l3regex}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage[columns=1]{idxlayout}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}


\ExplSyntaxOn
\AtBeginDocument{%
\LetLtxMacro\idxorig\index

\RenewDocumentCommand{\index}{o+m}{%
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {#2} % Store the index entry 
  \regex_replace_once:nnN {!}{,\~} \l_tmpa_tl % replacing
  \IfValueTF{#1}{%
    \idxorig[#1]{\tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl} % write the new index entry
  }{
    \idxorig{\tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl}% write the new index entry
  }
}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\makeindex



\begin{document}
John\index{Smith!John} and William Smith\index{Smith!William} 
were brothers.  Jack Jones\index{Jones!Jack} is another person.
\printindex
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update with the shorter version (as egreg suggested)**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage[columns=1]{idxlayout}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\AtBeginDocument{%
\LetLtxMacro\idxorig\index

\RenewDocumentCommand{\index}{o+m}{%
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {#2}
  \tl_replace_once:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl  {!}{,\ } 
  \IfValueTF{#1}{%
    \idxorig[#1]{\tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl}
  }{
    \idxorig{\tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl}
  }%
}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\makeindex


\begin{document}
John\index{Smith!John} and William Smith\index{Smith!William} 
were brothers.  Jack Jones\index{Jones!Jack} is another person.
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\tl_replace_once:Nnn` seems easier here.

Comment: Anyway, I'd use `{,\ }` (backslash space) in the replacement string. Not a big deal anyway. With `\tl_replace_once:Nnn` it would be `\tl_replace_once:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl { ! } { ,~ }`

Comment: @egreg: I always forgot about `\tl_replace_once:Nnn` -- I will change later on. Thanks for suggestion

Comment: Thanks. I've accepted the solution (and +1'd it), but I can't help but think fiddling with the parser is the wrong solution, and a redefinition of `\item` and `\subitem` would be better.  But I can't see how to do that simply, and your solution is nice and short.

Comment: @richard: You still have to 'parse' the '!' content away from being fed into item. Please consider that in fact `makeindex` generates the `.ind` file, not `LaTeX`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer.  Yes, I know `makeindex` is doing that.  I'm suggesting `makeindex` should be allowed to do its job unchanged, and the definition of `\item` and `\subitem` altered to cope with its output.  So far as I can tell the current definition of `\item` already does weird look-ahead stuff, so I think it should be possible.

Comment: @richard: The point is: `\index` will in final generate an `\indexentry` command in the `.idx` file --> `makeindex` grabs this and tries to parse the given data and sorts it accordingly -- redefining `\'subitem` to omit the `\par` and `\hspace` (see the `article.cls` for definition) is possible, but useless, since those commands appear too late. Smith John and William are still sorted and won't appear as two individual index entries as you requested. Changing the meaning of `!` must be done before `makeindex` sees the `!` at all!